# create a copy of an existing dictionary but assign a unique ID for the copy

Tags: python, dictionary, unique

I want to create a copy of a existing dict

```
b = {'name':'someone'}
copy_b = b
```

if do this, changes made in copy_b will affect b,
how can I make copy_b unique to b?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dict()

```
>>>a = {1:1}
>>>b = dict(a)
>>>b[2] = 2
>>>a
{1:1}
```

This will do good

Answer (score 1):

```
from copy import deepcopy

copy_b = deepcopy(d)
```

should work ... I would think at least

if its just a simple dictionary like above

```
copy_b = dict(d)
```